# C++:Getting too many initializers for ‘char [4]’ array error

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error when I try to compile some source code I'm working on. I'm very new to programming and arrays have been giving me a hard time for some reason:

```
airline2.cpp:9:84: error: too many initializers for ‘char [4]’
   char array_seats[][4] = {{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'},{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}};
```

And this is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char row, letter, answer;
  int letter2;

  char array_seats[][4] = {{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'},{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}};

  for (int row = 0; row <= 6; row++)
    {
      for (int letter = 0; letter <= 4; letter++)
    {
      cout << array_seats[row][letter] << " ";
    }
      cout << endl;
    }

  do
    {
      cout << "Enter your desired seat row:\n";
      cin >> row;
      cout << "Enter a seat letter:\n";
      cin >> letter;

      if(letter == 'A' || letter == 'a')
    letter2 = 1;
      else if(letter == 'B' || letter == 'b')
    letter2 = 2;
      else if(letter == 'C' || letter == 'c')
    letter2 = 3;
      else if(letter == 'D' || letter == 'd')
    letter2 = 4;

      if(array_seats[row-1][letter2] == 'X')
    cout << "Sorry, this seat is taken.\n" << endl;

      else
    {
      array_seats[row-1][letter2] = 'X';
      cout << "Seat reservation successful.\n" << endl;
    }

      for (int row = 0; row <= 6; row++)
    {
      for (int letter = 0; letter <= 4; letter++)
        {
          cout << array_seats[row][letter] << " ";
        }
      cout << endl;
    }

      cout << "Would you like to try again? (Y/N)\n";
      cin >> answer;

    }while (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');

  cout << "Have a good flight!\n";

  return 0;

}
```

I tried setting the error to 5 and adding '\0' at the end but nothing seems to work. Any help?

Comment: Change it to `char array_seats[][7]`.

Comment: Well it says _"too many initializes"_. Did you try reducing the number of initializers?

Comment: You're initializing an array to contain some arbitrary number of arrays of 4 characters.  You have two nested initializers - one with 7 characters and one with 3 characters.  So, given that, does the message "too many initializers" make sense given you're trying to initialize a 4 character array?

Comment: It seems like you want the array to contain either spaces or `'X'`, not the seat numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a syntax error in the way you are trying to initialize the 2D array.

```
  char array_seats[][4] = {{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'},{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}};
```

The above line means that, every row will have 4 elements. If you see the first row, it has 7 elements, {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'}. Reduce this to 4 elements and the compilation error would disappear. So your array_seats will now have 2 rows and 4 columns

**Note**: Doing above will solve the compilation error but your program suffers from serious runtime errors. Specifically when you're trying to access array_seats[ 2][0], etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
char array_seats[][4] = {{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'},{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}};
```

{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'} is over 4